# How to deal with wall-of-text questions?

Tags: discussion

Those not-to-the-point rambling questions that include information that isn't necessary to solve the problem.

I'm not sure what's worse, a full code dump with little explanation, or wall of text with little or no code.

Personally I just skip them. But is there a flag or policy that is appropriate for these lengthy questions?

Comment: Do you have any examples?

Comment: Sure I'll post some next time I see.

Comment: How about just editing out the irrelevant content?

Comment: Whoa!  Who is to decide what is irrelevant?  Assuming there is some problem in there, irrelevancy is not known unless you find the bug/s first!

Comment: I just skip them. You arent under any obligation to answer the question. If I dont feel like scaling the wall, I just walk past it.

Comment: It is work.  This is supposed to be fun, skipping is an obvious option that I often select.  There isn't anything wrong with posting a lengthy question, it is just not a good way to attract an answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> But is there a flag or policy that is appropriate for these lengthy questions?

There is no flag specifically for this - why should there be?

The policy is to get in there and edit it into shape. Remove the redundant text. Format the code (if any). Use bullet points or otherwise separate out the actual questions.

If you go through this process and find the question is still unclear or inadequately quantified then you should down vote it and/or vote to close if you have the privilege. Your editing attempt is not for nothing though - you've shown the OP how their question should look, and you've at least given the question a fighting chance to survive.

Answer (score 6):

9 out of 10 times these are open ended chatty questions because the OP can't break down their problem into a statement (this itself is a candidate for closure as too broad).

I usually start by [a] editing out background fluff [b] formatting the code (if any) [c] asking in a comment "what is the actual problem"? - if this doesn't help, then either I move on or flag for closure.

There is no stated policy but what is clear is that this is not a "chat community" and most of the times such wordy discussions get closed eventually.